# Route Id overrides Model.Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a route like this:

```
Conference/Committees/1
```

And within that page, it cycles through the Committees for a Conference (where the Conference Id = 1).

I have a partial view that renders an edit style page for a selected committee, with a route like this:

```
Conference/Committees/1?committeeId=2
```

In debug, the model data is correct, and the Committee has an Id = 2. However, when I use the following Razor statement:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

with the following model:

```
@model munhq.Models.Committee
```

The hidden input has an value of "1" instead of "2".

Is this a bug in MVC? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

If I replace

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

with

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />
```

it renders the correct Id value.

**Update 2**

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Committees(int id, PrivilegedAction? actionToTake, int? committeeId, ConferenceStatusMessage? csm)
    {
        Conference conference;
        HandleConferenceStatusMessage(csm);

        try
        {
            conference = await db.Conferences
            .Include(i => i.Committees.Select(c => c.CommitteeMemberCommitteeEntries))
            .Where(i => i.Id == id)
            .SingleAsync();

            HandleAction(actionToTake, conference);
            HandleAuthorisations(conference);
        }
        catch
        {
            return ConferenceActionFail();
        }

        if (committeeId == null)
        {
            if (conference.Committees.FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {
                committeeId = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                committeeId = conference.Committees.FirstOrDefault().Id;
            }

            ViewBag.ConferenceId = id; // used for adding a committee member entry

            return RedirectToAction("Committees", new { id = id, action = actionToTake, committeeId = committeeId, csm = csm });
        }
        else
        {
            if (CommitteeIsPartOfConference(conference, committeeId) || committeeId == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.SelectedCommittee = committeeId;
                ViewBag.JsonAvailableMembers = jsonAvailableCommitteeMembers(id);

                return View(conference);
            }
            else
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your controller code. i am sure the model that you have passed to the view has the id = 2

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan see update. Do you still need to see the controller code?

Comment: @nolly, the view doesn't tell what you have passed to it, it depends on your controller code that what data that passed object contains.

Comment: Added the controller code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using this before returning a view:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

In general when an `Action` gets called the framework builds a `ModelStateCollection` based on the query-string values, post-data, routing values etc. And this `ModelStateCollection` will be passed to the `View`. All the HTML input helpers try to the get the values from the `ModelStateCollection` first, before trying to get the values from the actual model. 
And that's the reason why your `Html.HiddenFor` extension works incorrectly (it checks for ModelStateCollection firstly) whereas your `<input type="hidden">` contains a correct value.

Comment: This is such an important feature. It's a shame it's not more obvious.

Comment: While overriding `CreateController` method of `DefaultControllerFactory` after call to `base.CreateController(x,y)`, it was making my model id set to zero. Above solution worked to get rid of this issue

Comment: Be aware that using that method you also clear the model validation errors and so any server-side only validation won't be show in the rendered view.