# @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id) retuning the wrong value for Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my home controller, i have an action method for an edit form set up like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Person p = DbPerson.GetPerson(id);

    return View(p);
}
```

The view:

```
@model Person

<h4 class="leftBG">Edit Form</h4>

id is : @Model.Id<br />
Name is : @Model.Name<br /><br />

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Id, new { })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { })

@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name, new { })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { })
```

when I navigate to to: `home/edit/1` 
I get the person with id = 1 and everything works as expected..

However if i go to `home/edit/199` 
(there is no person with id = 199 in the database)
the DbPerson.GetPereson gives back a person with id = 0

However in my view, the text box for id shows: `199`, i'm not sure why...

Is this expected behavior?

why is Model.Id is `0` , and yet the text box shows the value `199` ?

Comment: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360948/route-id-overrides-model-id), it's probably what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Try using ModelState.Clear(); before you return your view. It could be hanging onto old values.